# bootstrap active class is not working when i include it in another jsp file

Tags: javascript, java, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I have created a bootstrap navbar. I have written jquery for changing active class, and it's working fine.I wanted to include it in every jsp page.The problem is- active class is not working, when i include it in other jsp pages.
Below code is for including navbar, which is written in welcome.jsp:

```
<jsp:include page="navbar.jsp" />
```

And this below code is for changing active class of navbar, which is written in navbar.jsp

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".nav a").on("click", function(){
$(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
$(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
    });     
     </script>
```

Comment: That is the parent element?

Comment: sorry , which one you are asking?

Comment: the parent element?

Comment: i dont know much about jquery,i found that code somewhere.

Comment: you should not use jsp:include in your code.

Comment: then what should I use? I want navbar in every page.

Comment: you can create a tag.

Comment: which tag? I dont know tags in jsp. can you please elaborate.